# How can i update record on an embedded document in a mongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB "ratings" collection which contains the below data

```js
/* 1 */
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f1e13936d702dc8b1aa47c8"),
  "ratings": [{
      "music": "PN1",
      "rating": "23"
    },
    {
      "music": "PN2",
      "rating": "24"
    }
  ],
  "email": "test1@mail.com",
  "username": "test1"
}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f1e13f46d702dc8b1aa47c9"),
  "ratings": [{
      "music": "PN3",
      "rating": "45"
    },
    {
      "music": "PN4",
      "rating": "65"
    }
  ],
  "email": "test2@mail.com",
  "username": "test2"
}
```

I want to modify the PN1 rating for username "test1" and i execute the below code

```js
db.getCollection('ratings').update(
    // query 
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5f1e13936d702dc8b1aa47c8"),
      "email": "test1@mail.com"
    },

    // update 
    {
      "ratings.rating": "8"
    },

    // options 
    {
      "multi": false,
      "upsert": false
    );
```

The code works but instead of modifying just the PN1 rating for test1 user, the entire ratings list for that user was replaced the update. How can i fix this? I only want to modify the PN1 rating for the test1 user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to specify which element of the array you want to update, e.g. one that has a `music` value of `PN1`. You can do this by adding a field to the query that matches against the `ratings.music` field like so:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f1e13936d702dc8b1aa47c8"),
  "email": "test1@mail.com",
  "ratings.music": "PN1"
}
```

Now that you matched the document you want to update, you need to tell MongoDB how to update the document. An update document that changes the rating might look like this:

```
{
  $set:
        {
          "ratings.$.rating": 8
        }
}
```

This works by using the [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) positional operator, which will update the first element in the `ratings` array that has a `music` field equal to `PN1`.